# determining a prime factorization

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, prime-factorization

What is the prime factorizatíon of

$$N:= \sum_{n=1}^{10^8 -1} n^3 $$

writing the sum out, didn't help me..
therefore..any help is really appreciated!

Comment: When you say 'writing the sum' - please tell me that wasn't all 99,999,999 terms. Do you know about the standard formulae for sums of cubes: (https://brilliant.org/wiki/sum-of-n-n2-or-n3/) or (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_(algebra)#Sum_of_cubes_of_numbers_in_arithmetic_progression)

Comment: no haha. sorry i actually ment $ \frac{ ( 10^8 -1)^2 10^{16} }{4} $

Comment: @tomi that would take 1157 days 9 hours 46 minutes 39 seconds at one a second, be realistic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, $\sum_{n=1}^k n^3 =\frac {k^2(k+1)^2}4$

In your case $k=10^8 -1$

The sum is $\frac {(10^8-1)^2(10^8)^2}4$

$10^8-1=99999999=3^2 \times 11 \times 73 \times 101 \times 137$

$\frac {(10^8)^2}4=\frac {10^{16}}4=\frac{2^{16} \times 5^{16}}{2^2}=2^{14} \times 5^{16}$

So $\frac {(10^8-1)^2(10^8)^2}4=2^{14} \times 3^4 \times 5^{16} \times 11^2 \times 73^2 \times 101^2 \times 137^2 $